# Why i am getting NullReference Exception for Linq Left Outer Join with two Lists?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, left-join

i am trying to make left outer join for two lists where i am getting NullReference Exception.I am wondering why? Please help.

I have defined my sql query at the top(Comments) which works grea in sql server for the same joint but when i represented that query to LINQ it gives me error.

ContactList Having Data as

**ContactId**   **GroupId**    **FirstName**    **LastName**     **Phone**    **Email**

[image]

GroupList Having Data as

**GroupId**   **GroupName**

[image]

Here is the query i am trying for Left Outer Join.

```
       /*
       * select g.Id as 'Group Id',g.Name as 'Group Name',c.Id as 'Contact Id',
       c.FirstName,c.LastName,c.Phone,c.Email from Groups g left outer join Contacts c 
       on g.Id = c.GroupId 
       */
     var joinedList1 = (from g in lstAllGroups.AsEnumerable()
                        join c in lstAllContacts.AsEnumerable()
                        on  g.GroupId equals c.GroupId  into temp
                        from rg in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        orderby g.GroupId
                        select new 
                        {
                           GroupId = g.GroupId,
                           GroupName = g.GroupName,
                           ContactId = rg.ContactId == null ? 0 : rg.ContactId,
                           FirstName=rg.FirstName == null ?String.Empty: rg.FirstName,
                           LastName = rg.LastName == null ? String.Empty : rg.LastName,
                           Phone = rg.Phone == null ? String.Empty : rg.Phone,
                           Email = rg.Email == null ? String.Empty : rg.Email,
                         }).ToList();

    foreach (var item in joinedList1)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

**Note :** In Left Outer Join, GroupList is the first Datasource and ContactList is the second datasource.

Comment: Group 14 has no match, so `rg` will be null and `rg.ContactId` (among others) will throw an exception.

Comment: @DStanley - Thanks but how can  i solve this? What modification i should do in the code. Please help

Comment: Do you want a left join?  Or just an inner join?  If you want a left join what do you want to output if `rg` is null?

Comment: @DStanley - how can i check if "rg" is null or not? i am checking like this "ContactId = rg.ContactId == null ? 0 : rg.ContactId," for the fields...not the "rg". how can i achieve this ?

Comment: `ContactId = rg == null ? 0 : rg.ContactId`.  Review the "duplicate" question to better understand how to deal with null reference exceptions.